# How to read empty cells in PHPExcel without skipping values?

Tags: php, import-from-excel

I need your help to solve one problem.

I tried to find answer, but I found none.
I'm using PHPExcel 1.8.0 to read data from excel-file. And I'm using ReadFilter to read specific columns.

**Main PHP Code.**

```
        $price = UPLOAD_DIR . $price;

        $file_type = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($price);

        $filter = new ShipperReadFilter();

        $filter->getShipperSettings($shipper);          

        $reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($file_type)->setReadDataOnly(true)->setReadFilter($filter)->load($price);

        $worksheet = $reader->getActiveSheet();

        $col_number = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($worksheet->getHighestDataColumn());

        $data = array();

        foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator($filter->getStartRow()) as $row) {

            $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();

            $item = array();

            foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
                // May be PROBLEM is Here?
                array_push($item, $cell->getCalculatedValue());
            }

            array_push($data, $item);
        }           

        var_dump($data);
```

**ReadFilter code.**

```
class ShipperReadFilter implements PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter {

public $valid_columns = array();

public $start_row;

public function setValidColumns ($columns) {
    $this->valid_columns = $columns;
}

public function getShipperSettings ($shipper) {

    switch ($shipper) {

        // Shipper 1
        case 1 : 
            $this->setValidColumns(array('A', 'D', 'F'));
            $this->start_row = 4;
            break;

        // Shipper 2
        case 2 :
            $this->setValidColumns(array('A', 'R', 'T'));
            $this->start_row = 7;
            break;

        // Shipper 3
        case 3 :
            $this->setValidColumns(array('H', 'I', 'J'));
            $this->start_row = 14;
            break;
    }
}

public function getStartRow () {
    return $this->start_row;
}

public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = '') {

    if (in_array($column, $this->valid_columns)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}   
}
```

**Result**

```
array(3501) { 
   [0]=> array(2) { 
       [0]=> string(11) "01-00018239" 
       [1]=> float(2493) 
}
```

**But I need this**

```
array(3501) { 
[0]=> array(3) { 
    [0]=> string(11) "01-00018239" 
    [1]=> float(2493) 
    [2]=> null // or '', or 0
}
```

Is there the right way to solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the cell iterator will only iterate over cells that actually exist

```
$cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
$cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);

$item = array();
foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
    array_push($item, $cell->getCalculatedValue());
}
```

However, if all you're doing is building an array of calculated values for each row, then you might find that using the worksheet's rangeToArray() method is more efficient.

**EDIT**

To get only cells matching your read filter column list:

```
foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
    $item[$cell->getColumn()] = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
}
$item = array_intersect_key($item, array_flip($filter->valid_columns));
```

or

```
foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
    if(in_array($cell->getColumn(), $filter->valid_columns)) {
        array_push($item, $cell->getCalculatedValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Mark. This method works, but now ReadFilter doesn't work - reads all columns, but I want to read only 3 columns... Can you help?

Comment: The read filter doesn't read the cells for those columns that fall outside of your defined set..... if you try to get a value for a column that wasn't read, you'll get a NULL because the cell doesn't exist.... but the cell iterator has no idea about whether a column should exist because of a filter or not.... it will either iterate only the cells that exist, or iterate all cells

Comment: If you build your array of cells as an associative array, with the column id as the index; then do an array_intersect_keys with the column list for your shipper, then you'll have only those columns in the array